# How can I create a service that returns the value promise

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, angular-services

I want to create a service that returns a json

Or by request to to the server, or by checking if it exists already in: `Window.content`

But I don't want to get a promise from my Controller !

I want to get the json ready !

I have tried several times in several ways

I tried to use with `then` method to do the test in my Service

but I still get a promise

( Whether with `$http` only, and whether with `$q` )

I could not get the value without getting promise from my Controller

My Service :

```
app.service('getContent',['$http', function( $http ){

      return function(url){   // Getting utl

          if(window.content){ // if it's the first loading, then there is a content here

              var temp = window.content;
              window.content = undefined;
              return temp;
          }

          return $http.get(url);

      };

  }]);
```

My Controller:

```
.state('pages', {
   url: '/:page',
   templateProvider:['$templateRequest',
       function($templateRequest){
           return $templateRequest(BASE_URL + 'assets/angularTemplates/pages.html');
       }],
   controller: function($scope, $stateParams, getContent){ 
       //  Here I want to to get a json ready :
       $scope.contentPage = getContent(BASE_URL + $stateParams.page + '?angular=pageName');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If the data exists, just resolve it in a promise.**

While this process is still asynchronous it won't require a network call and returns quickly.

```
app.service('getContent',['$http', '$q', function( $http, $q ){

      return function(url){ 
          // create a deferred
          var deferred = $q.defer();
          if(window.content){ // if it's the first loading, then there is a content here

              var temp = window.content;
              window.content = undefined;
              deferred.resolve(temp); // resolve the data
              return deferred.promise; // return a promise
          }

          // if not, make a network call
          return $http.get(url);

      };

  }]);
```

Just to reiterate, this asynchronous, but it won't require a network call.

Comment: Thank you for answer
I did my controller in this way:

`controller: function($scope, $stateParams, getContent) {
   getContent(BASE_URL + $stateParams.page + '?angular=pageName').then(function(res){
       // By || Operator   -   get the promise of $htpp or the promise of $q
       $scope.contentPage = res.data || res;
   });
}`

Comment: Great to hear! If you found this helpful then please mark it as accepted. It's good to keep the unanswered queue clean.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. If the code responsible to calculate or retrieve the value relies on a promise, you will not be able to return the value extracted from the promise by your function.

**Explanation:** This can easily be seen from the control flow. A promise is evaluated asynchronously. It may take several seconds to retrieve json from a server, but the caller of your function should not wait so long because your whole runtime environment would block. This is why you use promises in the first place. Promises are just a nice way to organize callbacks. So when your promise returns, the event that caused the function call will have already terminated. In fact it must have, otherwise your promise could not be evaluated.

Comment: So only in the controller I most run the `then` method ?
It is not possible to run it in the service, at all ?
Because I have some controllers and I want them use with this service
so I thought  to do the test with `then` method in the srevice

Comment: It depends on where you want to use the data. You can run the .then method in the service but then you will have to use the result right there. If you want to pass the result from the service to the controller, you will have to return a promise as well.

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking about this wrong. A service always returns a promise, because there is no synchronous way of getting JSON from an API:

```
app.factory('myService', ['$http', function($http) {
    return $http('http://my_api.com/json', function(resp) {
        return resp.data;
    });
}]);
```

You would then call this within your controller like so:

```
app.controller('myController', ['$scope', 'myService', function($scope, myService) {
    myService.then(function(data) {
        $scope.contentPage = data; // here is your JSON 
    }, function(error) {
        // Handle errors
    });
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your service is returning a promise as it's written at the moment. A promise is always a promise, because you don't really know when it will be finished. However with Angular's 2 way data binding this isn't an issue. See my edits bellow as well as the example on `$HTTP` in the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#example)

In your controller

```
controller: function($scope, $stateParams, getContent){

       getContent(BASE_URL + $stateParams.page + '?angular=pageName')
                                    .then(aSuccessFn, aFailedFn);

        function aSuccessFn(response) {
            // work with data object, if the need to be accessed in your template, set you scope in the aSuccessFn.
            $scope.contentPage =  response.data;
        }
       function aFailedFn(data) {
            // foo bar error handling.
       }

   }
```